# Get Empty response with Passing Arraylist to SOAP service in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, arraylist

Hello friends i m passing latitude and longitude value in arraylist to soap web service in android below is my code

**Demo.Java**

```
public class Demo extends Activity
{       ArrayList<ParserLatLong>mArrayListParserLatLongs;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        public final String NAMESPACE = "***";
    public final String URL = *****";
    FrameLayout fram_map;
    public final String SOAP_ACTION_9 = "****";
    public final String METHOD_NAME_9 = "*****";
       @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setcontentView(R.layout.main);
         fram_map = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fram_map);
     mArrayListParserLatLongs=new ArrayList<ParserLatLong>();
            fram_map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            float x = event.getX();
                            float y = event.getY();

                            int x_co = Math.round(x);
                            int y_co = Math.round(y);

                            projection = mMap.getProjection();
                            Point x_y_points = new Point(x_co, y_co);

                            LatLng latLng = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(x_y_points);

                            int eventaction = event.getAction();

                            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == eventaction)
                                {
                                    // finger touches the screen

                                    if (Is_MAP_Moveable == false & val.size() != 0)
                                        {
                                            val.clear();
                                            polygon.remove();
                                        }

                                }

                            else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE == eventaction)
                                {
                                    // finger moves on the screen
                                    if (Is_MAP_Moveable == false)
                                        {
                                            System.out
                                                    .println("Lat "+latLng.latitude +"Lng "+latLng.longitude);
                                            ParserLatLong mLatLong=new ParserLatLong();
                                            mLatLong.setLat(String.valueOf(latLng.latitude));
                                            mLatLong.setLng(String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));
                                            mArrayListParserLatLongs.add(mLatLong);
                                            val.add(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude));
                                        }
                                }

                            else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == eventaction)
                                {

                                    if (Is_MAP_Moveable == false && val.size() > 0)
                                        {
                                            rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
                                            rectOptions.addAll(val);
                                            rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
                                            rectOptions.strokeWidth(2);
                                            rectOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
                                            polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
                                            new FetchPolygondata().execute();
                                        }
                                }

                            if (Is_MAP_Moveable == true)
                                {
                                    return false;

                                } else
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                        }
                });

    }
public class FetchPolygondata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Wait", "Loading ");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mAllMethods.check_Internet()==true) {

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_9); 
                for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListParserLatLongs.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(" LT : "+mArrayListParserLatLongs.get(i).getLat() +" LN : "+mArrayListParserLatLongs.get(i).getLng());
                    request.addProperty("alPolygon",mArrayListParserLatLongs.get(i).getLat()+","+mArrayListParserLatLongs.get(i).getLng());
                }


                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);

                try {
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_9, envelope);
                    SoapObject mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                    Object re= null;
                    re = envelope.getResponse();
                    System.out.println("Response "+re.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                mAllMethods.ShowDialog(getActivity(), "Validate", "Network not Available");
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (mProgressDialog!=null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }

     }
```

**And my SOAP web service page is like below **

[image]
when i run above code it will give me empty response means no value so any idea how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

please check only for  one `latitude-longitude` instead of  all . and check response if its `not null`?

and the problem is `latitude-longitude` being `null` or `""`. So, the response is not coming properly..

Please check only for one `latitude-longitude` output..you can try with putting static value too.

I hope it'll solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set debug flag for [HttpTransportSE](http://amigo.gforge.inria.fr/obr/v2/amigo_ksoap_binding/doc/api/org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransportSE.html) to true and print out the request and response dump of the SOAP service call in Logcat. Then use the Logcat requestdump with [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) like software to check out the actual request and response you are receiving from the service.

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_9, envelope);
        Log.d("HTTP REQUEST ",androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
        Log.d("HTTP RESPONSE", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
        ....

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```